# How to Rotate Left the elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays, rotation, logic

I want to Rotate these elements to left. Please Help me out ...

```
public class RotateLeft
{ 
     public static void main(String args[]) 
     { 
         int array[] ={1,2,3};
         int myarray[]= new int[3];               
         //Here is my logic                     
         for(int i=0; i<myarray.length-1; i++)
         {                         
             myarray[i]=array[i+1];
             myarray[i+1]=array[i];
         }
         System.out.print(myarray[0]+" "+myarray[1]+ " "+ myarray[2]);  
    }
}
```

output  should be 2 3 1

Comment: Do you have only 3 elements in array?

Comment: As long as the size is small and fixed, you could hard-code the solution(s) (I imagine that this would also improve execution time). If the size is variable, take a look at the possible duplicate for a generic solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int[] myarray = new int[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i <= myarray.length - 1; i++) {
    if (i != myarray.length - 1) {
        myarray[i] = array[i + 1];
    } else {
        myarray[i] = array[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong value gets sent "around the end" from `myarray[0]` to last item.  Think about what happens to `myarray[0]` on the **very first trip** through the loop...

Comment: Kevin Anderson, I did not get any problem with this for loop I tested with multiple test cases it is working fine, can u explain u r point with example?

Comment: Yeah, this works fine, whether the array is empty, contains only one item, or numerous items.

Comment: My bad; for some reason I thought it was rotating `array` inside itself, which would have required holding the initial value of `array[0]` in a temporary variable.